# Activities, services, broadcast receivers - Android Terminology

Tags: android, terminology

I'm new to android development and I'm trying to learn the proper terminology.
Are activities, services, broadcast receivers and content providers classes or classes instances (*objects*)?
(I've seen activities referred as classes or objects depending on the book or tutorial).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Android is based on Java** , and Activity, Services,Broadcast Receivers are all classes which extends a **Common Root class Object**.

So you can implement all the Object Oriented Programming Concepts with these classes.

Below is the Hierarchy of an Activity in Android system, similarly it is applicable for others too.

```
public class Activity 
extends ContextThemeWrapper implements LayoutInflater.Factory2,     
Window.Callback, KeyEvent.Callback, View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, ComponentCallbacks2


java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.content.Context
        ↳   android.content.ContextWrapper
           ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
               ↳    android.app.Activity
```

For more info you can check **developers.android.com**

Answer (score 0):

In short, they are both.

A class in Android (and Java in general) is the blueprint of your functionality, while an instance of that class is a concrete incarnation, holding it's own versions of the non-static member variables. This is often a source of confusion for newbies, since your `Activity` sub-class gets a new instance for each device configuration - rotation, language change, etc.

This is a very broad question, though. An extensive answer will take many many paragraphs of text. I suggest reading up on Java's basics regarding classes and objects.

Answer (score 0):

Activities are classes that run on foreground.Services are classes that run in background(Generally without a UI) which extend from Service class.Broadcast receiver are classes that listen to certain events when they are fired for example Boot completed,Charge Complete everything else.
In short all of them are classes